# How to create an array or collection of Dataset<Row>of spark-dataframes type?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am working in filtration of an avro file in spark using java. I am getting different Dataframes for different type of filtration conditions like (equalto,greater than, less than) as below:

```
df1 = sourceDf.filter(sourceDf.col(fieldName).equalTo(value)),
df2 = sourceDf.filter(sourceDf.col(fieldName).gt(value)),
df3 = sourceDf.filter(sourceDf.col(fieldName).lt(value)) and so on....
```

Now, i want to collect all dataframes(df1,df2,df3,...)` in one collection or array not individual ones as above.
please let me know how can i achieve this as i am new in java and apache-spark.

i tried Dataset[] RecordCollection = new Dataset[3]; but it is not allowed.

The exception is: "can't create a generic array of dataset"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish since the examples you post filters nothing if combined. but still you can do:

[`union`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#union-org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset-) from the API:

```java
Dataset<Row> df = df1.union(df2).union(df3)
```

or from the start filter using [`or`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html#or-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-):

```java
Column c1 = sourceDf.col(fieldName).equalTo(value);
Column c2 = sourceDf.col(fieldName).gt(value);
Column c3 = sourceDf.col(fieldName).lt(value);
df1 = sourceDf.filter(c1.or(c2).or(c3))
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. i want to create an array of different resultant datasets so that i can apply different logical conditions on them in next step like df1(with condition 1) OR df2(with condition) AND df3

Comment: So why not using `ArrayList`?

Comment: well, I tried to create ArrayList of Dataset<Row> type, but getting error. As i am new in Java as well as in spark, it will be helpful if you guide me..

Comment: for me `List<Dataset<Row>> list = new ArrayList<>();` works, show in the post your code